# implement kurento client for RN

Tags: react-native, kurento

I'm working on a streaming mobile application with ReactNative & i used Kurento media server.

I need to implement a kurento client on my RN app , you will find below the source code of my nodejs server. I need to implement a viewer on my RN. The signaling phase works as specified.

But how to display remote stream?

```
function nextUniqueId() {
    idCounter++;
    return idCounter.toString();
}

/*
 * Management of WebSocket messages
 */
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {

    var sessionId = nextUniqueId();
    console.log('Connection received with sessionId ' + sessionId);

    ws.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log('Connection ' + sessionId + ' error');
        stop(sessionId);
    });

    ws.on('close', function() {
        console.log('Connection ' + sessionId + ' closed');
        stop(sessionId);
    });

    ws.on('message', function(_message) {
        var message = JSON.parse(_message);
        console.log('Connection ' + sessionId + ' received message ', message);

        switch (message.id) {
        case 'presenter':
            startPresenter(sessionId, ws, message.sdpOffer, function(error, sdpAnswer) {
                if (error) {
                    return ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                        id : 'presenterResponse',
                        response : 'rejected',
                        message : error
                    }));
                }
                ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                    id : 'presenterResponse',
                    response : 'accepted',
                    sdpAnswer : sdpAnswer
                }));
            });
            break;

        case 'viewer':
            startViewer(sessionId, ws, message.sdpOffer, function(error, sdpAnswer) {
                if (error) {
                    return ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                        id : 'viewerResponse',
                        response : 'rejected',
                        message : error
                    }));
                }

                ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                    id : 'viewerResponse',
                    response : 'accepted',
                    sdpAnswer : sdpAnswer
                }));
            });
            break;

        case 'stop':
            stop(sessionId);
            break;

        case 'onIceCandidate':
            onIceCandidate(sessionId, message.candidate);
            break;

        default:
            ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                id : 'error',
                message : 'Invalid message ' + message
            }));
            break;
        }
    });
});
var minimist = require('minimist');
var argv = minimist(process.argv.slice(2), {
    default: {
        as_uri: 'http://192.168.1.103:8443/',
        ws_uri: 'ws://51.75.127.21:8888/kurento'
    }
});
/*
 * Definition of functions
 */

// Recover kurentoClient for the first time.
function getKurentoClient(callback) {
    if (kurentoClient !== null) {
        return callback(null, kurentoClient);
    }

    kurento(argv.ws_uri, function(error, _kurentoClient) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Could not find media server at address " + argv.ws_uri);
            return callback("Could not find media server at address" + argv.ws_uri
                    + ". Exiting with error " + error);
        }

        kurentoClient = _kurentoClient;
        callback(null, kurentoClient);
    });
}

function startPresenter(sessionId, ws, sdpOffer, callback) {
    clearCandidatesQueue(sessionId);

    if (presenter !== null) {
        stop(sessionId);
        return callback("Another user is currently acting as presenter. Try again later ...");
    }

    presenter = {
        id : sessionId,
        pipeline : null,
        webRtcEndpoint : null
    }

    getKurentoClient(function(error, kurentoClient) {
        if (error) {
            stop(sessionId);
            return callback(error);
        }

        if (presenter === null) {
            stop(sessionId);
            return callback(noPresenterMessage);
        }

        kurentoClient.create('MediaPipeline', function(error, pipeline) {
            if (error) {
                stop(sessionId);
                return callback(error);
            }

            if (presenter === null) {
                stop(sessionId);
                return callback(noPresenterMessage);
            }
            pipe = pipeline;
            presenter.pipeline = pipeline;
            pipeline.create('WebRtcEndpoint', function(error, webRtcEndpoint) {
                if (error) {
                    stop(sessionId);
                    return callback(error);
                }

                if (presenter === null) {
                    stop(sessionId);
                    return callback(noPresenterMessage);
                }

                presenter.webRtcEndpoint = webRtcEndpoint;

                if (candidatesQueue[sessionId]) {
                    while(candidatesQueue[sessionId].length) {
                        var candidate = candidatesQueue[sessionId].shift();
                        webRtcEndpoint.addIceCandidate(candidate);
                    }
                }

                webRtcEndpoint.on('OnIceCandidate', function(event) {
                    var candidate = kurento.getComplexType('IceCandidate')(event.candidate);
                    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                        id : 'iceCandidate',
                        candidate : candidate
                    }));
                });

                webRtcEndpoint.processOffer(sdpOffer, function(error, sdpAnswer) {
                    if (error) {
                        stop(sessionId);
                        return callback(error);
                    }

                    if (presenter === null) {
                        stop(sessionId);
                        return callback(noPresenterMessage);
                    }

                    callback(null, sdpAnswer);
                });

                webRtcEndpoint.gatherCandidates(function(error) {
                    if (error) {
                        stop(sessionId);
                        return callback(error);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
}

function startViewer(sessionId, ws, sdpOffer, callback) {
    clearCandidatesQueue(sessionId);

    if (presenter === null) {
        stop(sessionId);
        return callback(noPresenterMessage);
    }

    presenter.pipeline.create('WebRtcEndpoint', function(error, webRtcEndpoint) {
        if (error) {
            stop(sessionId);
            return callback(error);
        }
        viewers[sessionId] = {
            "webRtcEndpoint" : webRtcEndpoint,
            "ws" : ws
        }

        if (presenter === null) {
            stop(sessionId);
            return callback(noPresenterMessage);
        }

        if (candidatesQueue[sessionId]) {
            while(candidatesQueue[sessionId].length) {
                var candidate = candidatesQueue[sessionId].shift();
                webRtcEndpoint.addIceCandidate(candidate);
            }
        }

        webRtcEndpoint.on('OnIceCandidate', function(event) {
            var candidate = kurento.getComplexType('IceCandidate')(event.candidate);
            ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                id : 'iceCandidate',
                candidate : candidate
            }));
        });

        webRtcEndpoint.processOffer(sdpOffer, function(error, sdpAnswer) {
            if (error) {
                stop(sessionId);
                return callback(error);
            }
            if (presenter === null) {
                stop(sessionId);
                return callback(noPresenterMessage);
            }

            presenter.webRtcEndpoint.connect(webRtcEndpoint, function(error) {
                if (error) {
                    stop(sessionId);
                    return callback(error);
                }
                if (presenter === null) {
                    stop(sessionId);
                    return callback(noPresenterMessage);
                }

                callback(null, sdpAnswer);

                webRtcEndpoint.gatherCandidates(function(error) {
                    if (error) {
                        stop(sessionId);
                        return callback(error);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
}

function clearCandidatesQueue(sessionId) {
    if (candidatesQueue[sessionId]) {
        delete candidatesQueue[sessionId];
    }
}

function stop(sessionId) {
    if (presenter !== null && presenter.id == sessionId) {
        for (var i in viewers) {
            var viewer = viewers[i];
            if (viewer.ws) {
                viewer.ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                    id : 'stopCommunication'
                }));
            }
        }
        presenter.pipeline.release();
        presenter = null;
        viewers = [];

    } else if (viewers[sessionId]) {
        viewers[sessionId].webRtcEndpoint.release();
        delete viewers[sessionId];
    }

    clearCandidatesQueue(sessionId);

    if (viewers.length < 1 && !presenter) {
        console.log('Closing kurento client');
        if(kurentoClient) kurentoClient.close();
        kurentoClient = null;
    }
}

function onIceCandidate(sessionId, _candidate) {
    var candidate = kurento.getComplexType('IceCandidate')(_candidate);

    if (presenter && presenter.id === sessionId && presenter.webRtcEndpoint) {
        console.info('Sending presenter candidate');
        presenter.webRtcEndpoint.addIceCandidate(candidate);
    }
    else if (viewers[sessionId] && viewers[sessionId].webRtcEndpoint) {
        console.info('Sending viewer candidate');
        viewers[sessionId].webRtcEndpoint.addIceCandidate(candidate);
    }
    else {
        console.info('Queueing candidate');
        if (!candidatesQueue[sessionId]) {
            candidatesQueue[sessionId] = [];
        }
        candidatesQueue[sessionId].push(candidate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi crim94, did you implement kurento client into in your react -native project ?Can you provide any code snippet if its exist